# How to read browsers certificates uisng java on linux? by using keyStore.getInstance("xyz")

Tags: java

Am trying to read the installed certificates by using code

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY")  
ks.load(null, null)    
Enumeration<String> enumeration = ks.aliases()  
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {    
String string = (String) enumeration.nextElement()    
System.out.println(string)   
}
```

this code list out the installed certificates on windows but on linux doesn't? tried by changing the keystore providers also.

Comment: Are you trying to read certificates on a command-line/server application or in an applet?

Comment: in an applet. thanks @ Bert Jan Schrijver

Comment: alright, what's your use case? why do yo need to access installed certificates?

Comment: For digital sign login authentication  purpose. For my application.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with "read browsers certificates". 
Are you trying to read certificates from the default Java keystore? What's your goal?

KeyStore.getInstance(..) instantiates a keystore with a specific type (JKS, for example). When you want to read from a specific keystore, you need to specify the path to the keystore and make the KeyStore instance load that file.

See http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/RetrievingaKeyPairfromaKeyStore.htm for an example and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html for more details.

Edited: updated answer after clarified question.

You can find more info on reading browser keystores in Linux on:

1. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/keystores.html
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/JSS
3. [applet with SunMSCapi not working in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23868828/applet-with-sunmscapi-not-working-in-linux)
4. http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=12037571

Comment: here my problem is, i want list out the certificates which are installed by user on linux system. not specific certificate details. i have edited my post pleae check it once. thanks @bert jan

Answer (score 0):

Try with `libsoftokn3.so` of NSS.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653233/nss-jss-load-user-imported-cert-along-with-pkcs11-smartcard-in-java), "Approach 1".

The key is to find where `libsoftokn3.so` is, and use it as the libfile to construct a config file, and then a KeyStore.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Default Type.
Try the below code

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
```