# NSS/JSS: load user imported cert along with PKCS#11 smartcard in Java

Tags: java, client-certificates, nss

### Scenario

I am working on a Java Swing project, where I must develop a feature of listing certificates for users to choose for authentication via SSL against the server.

These certificates must contain the user imported ones in Firefox, and if a smartcard is inserted, those in the card will be listed, too. The environment is Linux/MacOS. In Windows the Internet Explorer handles it all, and what we would like to achieve is much like what happens in Windows: list all certificates, along with those in card, for users to choose.

---

### Situation

When using NSS (Network Security Service) of Mozilla in Ubuntu, I found I am lost. With no code samples for using JSS in Java, I can only get it to work partially, depending on the way how I load the config file for the provider.

What I do now, is:

1. read the cert in firefox (with `KeyStore`, `Provider` and `KeyStore.Builder`, loading the `softokn.so` as the library).
2. Load the cert from card with `CryptoManager` and get all its modules.
   (`CryptoManager.initialize(profileDir)`, `cm.getModules()`, `module.getTokens()`, etc. )

---

### Problem

#### Approach 1

If I load the provider with `libsoftoken3.so`, I can see the user certificates. But, when I initialize the `CryptoManager` after constructing the `provider`, the external modules (e.g., my smart cards) are not listed in `cryptoManager.getModules()`.

```
config = "library=" + NSS_JSS_Utils.NSS_LIB_DIR + "/libsoftokn3.so\n"
            + "name=\"Soft Token\"\n"
            + "slot=2\n" //for softoken, can only be 2.
            + "attributes=compatibility\n"
            + "allowSingleThreadedModules=true\n"
            + "showInfo=true\n"
            + "nssArgs=\"configdir='" + NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath() + "' "
                + "certPrefix='' "
                + "keyPrefix='' "
                + "secmod='secmod.db' "
                + "flags='readOnly'\""
//              + "flags='noDb'\""
            + "\n";
```

#### Approach 2

If I load the provider with NNS's `secmod.db`, the card will be listed, **even if it's not present/inserted**, in the `keyStore` constructed with this `provider`. When it's inserted, in the second step above, I can see the external modules, but then the card is listed twice, with the same alias.

```
config = "name=\"NSS Module\"\n"
            + "attributes=compatibility\n"
            + "showInfo=true\n"
            + "allowSingleThreadedModules=true\n"
            + "nssUseSecmod=true\n"
            + "nssSecmodDirectory=" + NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath();
```

---

Question:

- How can I easily load all certificate in a simple way, not separately with JSS?
- If it's not possible, how can I configure the provider to load them separately but without repetition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have somehow succeeded in solving it. 80% of my questions are solved by myself.........I think it's normal.

**Basically it consists in constructing two instances of `KeyStore` and two instances of `Provider`, each for each, one for user certificates and the other for smartcard.**

1. Construct a provider with `libsoftokn.so`, e.g., the first `config` in my question, and insert it. With `KeyStore.Builder` and this provider, build a `KeyStore softKeyStore`. In this keystore you have all the user certificates. Extract the information of these certificates and list them in a `JTable`.
2. Insert the smartcard before the first time `CryptoManager` is initialized. (If not, the card will be ignored until restarting the app.)
3. Initialize `CryptoManager`. Here some tricks to break the dead loop of `AlreadyInitializedException`/`NotInitializedException`:

We have:

```
private static void initializeCryptoManager() throws Exception {
    //load the NSS modules before creating the second keyStore.

    if (cm == null) { //cm is of type CryptoManager
        while (true) { //the trick.
            try {
                cm = CryptoManager.getInstance();
            } catch (NotInitializedException e2) {
                try {
                    InitializationValues iv = new InitializationValues(NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath());
                    //TEST
                    iv.installJSSProvider = false;
                    iv.removeSunProvider = false;
                    iv.initializeJavaOnly = false; //must be false, or native C error if no provider is created.
                    iv.cooperate = false;
                    iv.readOnly = true;
                    iv.noRootInit = true;
                    iv.configDir = NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath();
                    iv.noModDB = false;
    //              iv.noCertDB = false; 
    //              CustomPasswordCallback cpc = new  CustomPasswordCallback();
    //              iv.passwordCallback = cpc; //no passwordcallback needed here.
                    iv.forceOpen = false;
                    iv.PK11Reload = false;
                    CryptoManager.initialize(iv);
                    continue; // continue to getInstance.
                } catch (KeyDatabaseException | CertDatabaseException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
                    Traza.error(e);
                    throw e;
                } catch (AlreadyInitializedException e1) {
                    continue; //if is initialized, must go on to get cm.
                }
            } 
            break; //if nothing is catched, must break to end the loop.
        }
    }
}
```

And now, we can do `cm.getModules()` and `module.getTokens()`, to recognize the card. **Only when the card is inserted, the relevant module and its token will be present. **

4. When we get to the token of the card, check if it needs login and if it's logged. And, we must exclude the `InternalCryptoToken` and `InternalKeyStorageToken`.

So:

```
if (!token.isInternalCryptoToken() && !token.isInternalKeyStorageToken()){ // If not Internal Crypto service, neither Firefox CA store
    if (token.isPresent() ) { // when the card is inserted
        if (!token.isLoggedIn()){ // Try to login. 3 times.
            Traza.info("Reading the certificates from token " + token.getName() + ". Loggining... ");
            while (UtilTarjetas.tries <= 3) {
                try {
                //TEST
                    token.setLoginMode(NSS_JSS_Utils.LOGIN_MODE_ONE_TIME); 
                    token.login((PasswordCallback) new CustomPasswordCallback());
                    UtilTarjetas.prevTryFailed = false;
                    cm.setThreadToken(token);
                    break;
                } catch (IncorrectPasswordException e){
                    UtilTarjetas.prevTryFailed = true;
                    UtilTarjetas.tries ++;
                } catch (TokenException e) {
                    UtilTarjetas.prevTryFailed = true;
                    UtilTarjetas.tries ++;
                } 
            }

                // if tries > 3
                if (UtilTarjetas.tries > 3) {
                    Traza.error("The token " + token.getName() + " is locked now. ");
                    throw new IOException("You have tries 3 times and now the card is locked. ");
                }
            }

            if (token.isLoggedIn()) {
                ....
            }
```

When the token is logged in, execute shell script with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)` to use `modutil` shipped with NSS.

In shell it's like this:

```
modutil -dbdir /your/firefox/profile/dir -rawlist
```

This command shows you information contained in `secmod.db` in readable format.

```
 name="NSS Internal PKCS #11 Module" parameters="configdir=/home/easternfox/.mozilla/firefox/5yasix1g.default-1475600224376 certPrefix= keyPrefix= secmod=secmod.db flags=readOnly " NSS="trustOrder=75 cipherOrder=100 slotParams={0x00000001=[slotFlags=RSA,RC4,RC2,DES,DH,SHA1,MD5,MD2,SSL,TLS,AES,SHA256,SHA512,Camellia,SEED,RANDOM askpw=any timeout=30 ] 0x00000002=[ askpw=any timeout=0 ] }  Flags=internal,critical"

library=/usr/lib/libpkcs11-dnie.so name="DNIe NEW"  

library=/usr/local/lib/libbit4ipki.so name="Izenpe local"  NSS="  slotParams={0x00000000=[ askpw=any timeout=0 ] }  "
```

So you can analyze the output and get the library location in the line where your `module.getName()` are located. We can use `StringTokenizer`.

```
//divide the line into strings with "=".
StringTokenizer tz = new StringTokenizer(line, "=");
//get the first part, "library". 
String token = tz.nextToken(); 
//get the second part, "/usr/local/lib/libbit4ipki.so name"
token = tz.nextToken();
....
```

5. Then, with the file path of the `.so` driver, construct a `config` string to load another provider.

We will have:

```
String config = "name=\"" + moduleName + "\"\n" + "library=" + libPath;
```

`moduleName` is better escaped with "\", because it usually contains spaces. `libPath` should be escaped, if there would like to be spaces. Better not to have spaces.

Insert this provider, and construct a `cardKeyStore` with the same provider.

```
Provider p = new SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes()));
Security.insertProviderAt(p, 1);
KeyStore.Builder builder = null;
builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", p, 
    new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(new UtilTarjetas().new CustomCallbackHandler()));
cardKeyStore = builder.getKeyStore();
```

6. List the alias of the certificates we get from `cardKeyStore` in the same `JTable` we used above, along with those of `softKeyStore`.
7. When the user select a row in the `JTable`, get the selected alias and store it in a static field.
8. When we need a keystore to construct  `KeyManagerFactory` and `X509KeyManager` for SSL communication, with the static `alias` we look it up in `softKeyStore` and then `cardKeyStore`.

Like:

```
if (softKeyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
    return softKeyStore;
} else if (cardKeyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
    return cardKeyStore;
}
```

9. SSL handshake, sending messages, receiving, signing, etc.

Comment: Any idea how to get it to load in MacOS? I kept getting `Multi-threaded initialization failed: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DEVICE_ERROR`, weird thing is that it works when I try to read the FF keystore in Windows. I replaced the lib as well as FF profile directory to use the MacOS stuff of course, but still no go.

Comment: Aha.. I haven't tested it on MacOS. I have seen your post and I will answer there. Some guesses.